# HTTP request to unity HTTP server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to control my models with an external app. The idea is that when the unity project is executed the project spawns a HTTP Server with routes (just an idea) like **IP_ADDRESS/MODEL_NAME/rotate**.

Within the app I have some buttons. For example when I click the button "rotate" the app should send a HTTP request to the HTTP server which has been spawned by unity. When the server receives the request I want to rotate the object (in this example).

The unity project (or the executable) is always in the same network as the app. So these components only communicate within the same network.

Is this a suitable way to do this? Has C# already something like this build in? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to use Unity3d Networking, the wheel is done!

Comment: HTTP on a device on same local network? Why HTTP? Are you trying to make a multiplayer game?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Programmer No, not a game. Some 3D-Models with animations which should be controllable via app. HTTP was just an idea but not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @joreldraw I will look into that!

Comment: If HTTP is an idea then do what Joreldraw suggested. Use Unity's networking called UNET. Tutorial is here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-unet-multiplayer-tutorials-making-a-basic-survival-co-op.325692/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, since Unity is built on .NET, you can just use .NET's native libraries. HttpListener is available as far back as 2.0, which is (approximately) what Unity uses. This link will take you to the documentation, which also includes examples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Cheers!

Comment: Is that multi platform